# Script not working in post content

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
Search: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myfunction()">
<a id="sear" href="" target="_blank">Search</a>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var  x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=all+"+x+"&biw=1366&bih=643&source=lnms&tbm=isch";
document.getElementById("sear").href=url;
}
</script>
```

This code is changing into the following code when I add it to wordpress page editor and is not working.

```
Search: <input id="fname" type="text" />
<a id="sear" target="_blank"></a>Search
<script>// <![CDATA[
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=all+"+x+"&biw=1366&bih=643&source=lnms&tbm=isch";
document.getElementById("sear").href=url;
}
// ]]></script>
```

Is there a solution to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this markup where you would like to before footer. you can put this markup in page editor text mode too. But doing so will remain in that page alone. so place it in template files.

```
    Search: <input type="text" id="fname" >
    <a id="sear" href="" target="_blank">Search</a>
```

write a function and hook it to `wp_footer`, place the code in **funcitons.php**.

```
        function output_custom_script(){
          ?>
          <script>
           document.getElementById('fname').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var  x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=all+"+x+"&biw=1366&bih=643&source=lnms&tbm=isch";
    document.getElementById("sear").href=url;
}, false);
          </script>
         <?php
        }
        add_action('wp_footer','output_custom_script');
```

Check this [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snzyedy8/)

Comment: So you want me to add the script code that you have written in function.php and the code in page editor (I need it only on a single page) right?

Comment: yes, put the markup in your page editor and the functions in your current active theme functions.php

Comment: once you see this works. you can even output the script on particular page with page id using `is_page()` function condition.

Comment: Did that but on clicking the link, it is loading the same page. The google search window is not opening.

Comment: Its looks like you have an JS error too. Please use the updated code in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't use script in post editor.

Go to 
->Appearance > Editor
-> From right side bar select header.php and paste this code :

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var  x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=all+"+x+"&biw=1366&bih=643&source=lnms&tbm=isch";
document.getElementById("sear").href=url;
}
</script>
```

in header.php before closing tag of head `</head>`

Comment: Yes, I copied the script to header. The code still is not working and changes to: " Search: <input id="fname" type="text" />
<a id="sear" target="_blank"></a>Search "

Comment: What you are copying header.php ?

Comment: I copied the script part that you have shown to the header and the code to the wordpress page editor. I need that to be in the body.

Comment: Copy script in header use html in post editor by clicking on "Text" from right side and after that don't click on visual.

Comment: Tried that and now the link become clickable, but on click, it is loading the same page and not the google search

Comment: Its issue in your JS, put new question here. Its out of the scope from this question.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209069/javascript-in-page-doesnt-open-new-window