# JavaScript in page doesn't open new window

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
Search: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myfunction()">
<a id="sear" href="" target="_blank">Search</a>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var  x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=all+"+x+"&biw=1366&bih=643&source=lnms&tbm=isch";
document.getElementById("sear").href=url;
}
</script>
```

I have implemented this in WordPress and the link is now pointing to the same page rather than opening the google search page.

Comment: Please add debug information to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `onkeyup="myfunction()"`. Your function is named myFunction, not myfunction (function names are case sensitive).

Comment: But he is looking for to click on submit i believe.

Comment: Probably yes, but the question was why the posted code doesn't work, not how to write it better, so i just explained why it doesn't work and what is needed to be done. But you're right, that better option will be just do it once, on click.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in your JS code and the html that you are not calling your JS function.

Try this code :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjYRex

Put script in header.php and user HTML in post editor.

PS: Its good practice to enquee the script properly so it goes in footer.

Comment: There is one problem with your code: `window.open(url, '_blank');` will not necessarily open new tab. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)